# Combine all push notifications into one

Tags: android, push-notification, android-notifications

I'm using Parse Push Notifications to notify my app's users, but when I send 2 push notifications, I want them to be combined into one.

As you can see in [this image](http://s30.postimg.org/d7adb4ttt/image.jpg), WhatsApp combines all notifications into one. How can I do such a thing?

So far I have found this code:

```
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder()
     .setContentTitle("5 New mails from " + sender.toString())
     .setContentText(subject)
     .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
     .setLargeIcon(aBitmap)
     .setStyle(new Notification.InboxStyle()
         .addLine(str1)
         .addLine(str2)
         .setContentTitle("")
         .setSummaryText("+3 more"))
     .build();
```

But I don't know where or how to use it.

Comment: did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how it works in parse, but I have done the same for GCM. We have used a scheduler at the backed for pushing notifications after say every 5 minutes. There is a notification table which contains all the notifications with a status which is updated from the front end if the user receives a notification and performs some action, we update the table via a web service.

So suppose you have pushed 1st notification request(remember to define a unique key for this: collapse key) to the Google server and it did not reach the user, now when the scheduler re-checks for pending notifications it will re-pick the 1st one and there are few more new notifications to be pushed of similar kind. You can create a new request combining these and send request to the Google server.

```
{ "collapse_key": "score_update",
  "time_to_live": 108,
  "delay_while_idle": true,
  "data": {
     "score": "4 x 8",
     "time": "15:16.2342"
   },
  "registration_ids":["4", "8", "15", "16", "23", "42"]
}
```

You need to define a unique collapse key for your notifications, and if you create a new request with same collapse key all the previous pending requests will be discarded and only the latest one will be pushed to the users mobile which could be a list of couple of notifications.

Answer (score 0):

[The Android guide on notifications](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) really explains all this very well. You can also look at the [Android Notification design guide](https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html) to get some additional ideas about how to best use notifications.

To use the notification you've built, add this code:

```
final NotificationManager notificationManager =
(NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
// mId allows you to update the notification later on.
notificationManager.notify(mId, noti);
```

Later you can then update the notification to change its content, such as described there:

> To set up a notification so it can be updated, issue it with a notification ID by calling NotificationManager.notify(). To update this notification once you've issued it, update or create a NotificationCompat.Builder object, build a Notification object from it, and issue the Notification with the same ID you used previously. If the previous notification is still visible, the system updates it from the contents of the Notification object. If the previous notification has been dismissed, a new notification is created instead.

Answer (score -2):

Just use `setGroup(Group-KEY`) while setting notifications.

```
final static String GROUP_KEY_EMAILS = "group_key_emails";

// Build the notification, setting the group appropriately

Notification notif = new NotificationCompat.Builder(mContext)
         .setContentTitle("New mail from " + sender1)
         .setContentText(subject1)
         .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.new_mail)
         .setGroup(GROUP_KEY_EMAILS)
         .build();
```